# How to generate text fragment for selected text?

Tags: javascript

Text fragments are annotated http links that include "selected text". I want to generate a text fragment link for user selected text.

I am referring to the text fragments that were first announced when Google Chrome 80 came out.

References:

- https://web.dev/text-fragments/
- https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Text_fragments

Example: [https://ray.run/blog#:~:text=learned%20scaling](https://ray.run/blog#:%7E:text=learned%20scaling)

[image]

> Notice that the "Playwright" is highlighted when you open the page.

I am able to get a basic version working by using `window.getSelection().toString()` and encoding the string myself, but this breaks for non-trivial text selections.

Note that the syntax is not as simple as a basic kebab-case string.

```
#:~:text=[prefix-,]textStart[,textEnd][,-suffix]
```

As far as I can tell, there is no simple way to generate such expression using `window.getSelection()`.

I am trying to identify if there is a native browser API that would construct such a string.

Answer (score 2):

So I've already figured out an answer to this question, but decided to still post the question-answer because it took quite a bit of reading and a few false-starts.

First of all, if you are reading this today, most of the modern browsers (85%) already support text fragments ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_a_text_fragments)), so you most likely do not need a [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/text-fragments-polyfill) to make the navigate-and-highlight behavior to work.

You can check if client's browser supports the feature by checking if [`document.fragmentDirective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Text_fragments) is defined.

However, as far as my understanding goes, [there is no](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment/issues/160) public API to generate URLs from selection/range.

The closest thing I've found is `generateFragment` function provided by the earlier mentioned polyfill.

```
import { generateFragment } from 'text-fragments-polyfill/dist/fragment-generation-utils.js';

// generateFragment(window.getSelection());
```

I found it referenced in this [MDN article](https://web.dev/text-fragments/#programmatic-text-fragment-link-generation). However, note that the MDN article provided code example is stale/incorrect. The correct code:

```
import { generateFragment } from 'text-fragments-polyfill/dist/fragment-generation-utils.js';

export const generateTextFragment = (selection: Selection): string | null => {
  const result = generateFragment(selection);

  if (result.status !== 0) {
    return null;
  }

  let url = `${location.origin}${location.pathname}${location.search}`;

  const fragment = result.fragment;
  const prefix = fragment.prefix
    ? `${encodeURIComponent(fragment.prefix)}-,`
    : '';
  const suffix = fragment.suffix
    ? `,-${encodeURIComponent(fragment.suffix)}`
    : '';
  const start = encodeURIComponent(fragment.textStart);
  const end = fragment. textEnd ? `,${encodeURIComponent(fragment. textEnd)}` : '';

  url += `#:~:text=${prefix}${start}${end}${suffix}`;

  return url;
};
```

> Appears that at some point `.start` changed to `.textStart`.

This generally works, but produces a rather clunky experience (if you look at the implementation of `generateFragment` there is a lot going on). Therefore, heads up that you will most likely want to debounce or somehow otherwise throttle when you invoke this function.

This generally works:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();

  if (!selection) {
    return;
  }

  history.replaceState(null, '', generateTextFragment(selection));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, [fixed the article](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web.dev/pull/10112). There's a [pending PR](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/text-fragments-polyfill/pull/148) to remove the `text` prefix, but it's not merged yet, so the article was originally over-eagerly updated.

Comment: I published a blog post summarizing learnings from the above https://ray.run/blog/webs-most-underutilized-api-text-fragments Hope more context on subject starts appearing on the Internet.